# How do I display data from a django rest get request in a react-leaflet using onEachFeature?

Tags: leaflet, geodjango, react

I imported shapefiles into my PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension and created a REST API using Django which has a GET response like this:

```
[
{
    "objectid": 1,
    "id_field": 5543,
    "county_nam": "B1",
    "const_code": 288,
    "constituen": "KAM",
    "county_cod": 47,
    "shape_leng": 1.55978672217,
    "shape_area": 0.057422949
},
{
    "objectid": 2,
    "id_field": 6634,
    "county_nam": "B2",
    "const_code": 3,
    "constituen": "KIS",
    "county_cod": 1,
    "shape_leng": 0.88558616055,
    "shape_area": 0.02332510618
},
{
    "objectid": 3,
    "id_field": 6600,
    "county_nam": "B3",
    "const_code": 10,
    "constituen": "KIN",
    "county_cod": 2,
    "shape_leng": 4.28418177601,
    "shape_area": 0.75826601303
},
{
    "objectid": 4,
    "id_field": 6731,
    "county_nam": "B4",
    "const_code": 13,
    "constituen": "KAL",
    "county_cod": 3,
    "shape_leng": 5.33308007101,
    "shape_area": 1.02533838151
}, ...
```

How do I display this response into a React Leaflet?

```
   async componentDidMount() {
    const rawcurrentuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));

    await axios.get('/api/gis/counties/')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ county: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

When I display as below, the data is not displayed.

```
<Map center={position} zoom={7} ref={this.mapRef}>
 {this.state.county && (
        <GeoJSON
          data={this.state.county}
        />
      )}
 </Map>
```

Displaying with Django view works fine using onEachFeature:

```
myLayer = new L.geoJson(data, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.bindPopup('<font size="4">' + feature.properties.county_nam)
        },
        style: countStyle
 }).addTo(count).addTo(map);
```

How do I use the same concept in my current React scenario?

Comment: Please don't post the same question again. If you have some new/changed info, you can edit original one [Query a region within a larger region with geodjango rest api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386532/query-a-region-within-a-larger-region-with-geodjango-rest-api)

Comment: Well that question has no answer yet

Comment: @TomazicM any clues on this? I'm really stuck

Comment: Your data does not contain any geometries. It's perfectly normal that you cannot display them if they're not there in the source.

Comment: Well, i tried displaying them a while ago using just django view and it displays fine .. This challenge comes in when I try to display with react